# List of example questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Since it's hard to find examples of questions with various attributes, maybe we can turn this into a reference?

Here's the problem: I want to try out the `locked_date` attribute in one of my apps, but I can't find a post that's locked.

> ## **List:**
>
> **Questions**
>
> - Closed: [3003308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003308/general-practice-to-specify-a-break-after-a-default-clause-closed) (Stack Overflow)
> - Migrated: [2965](https://stackapps.com/questions/2965/mystacks-stack-overflow-trilogy-iphone-app-free) (Stack Apps)
> - Locked and Closed: [2835801](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835801/) (Stack Overflow)
> - Protected: [17207](https://superuser.com/questions/17207) (Supe rUser)
> - Locked and Protected: [84556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556) (Stack Overflow)
> - With Suggested Edits: [8468297](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468297) (Stack Overflow)
>
> **Answers**
>
> - Locked: [184673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/184673#184673) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: Also, can't answers be locked / protected too? Can someone please add examples of those?

Comment: Answers cannot be protected, because you cannot provide answers to answers...

Comment: @jjnguy: Right, but they can be locked, right?

Comment: Yes, answers can be locked.

Comment: Anyone got an example of one?

Comment: @George, I added one.