# MyStacks - "Stack Overflow trilogy" iPhone app (free)

Tags: app, iphone

v.1.3 of MyStacks, an unofficial iPhone app for browsing questions on the Stack Overflow trilogy sites, is [now available in the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mystacks/id360030953?mt=8).

**Current Version**

- Saves articles offline once viewed
- Choose active, featured, week or
  month feed.
- Search articles
- Browse specific tags
- Instantly swap between superuser.com, stackoverflow.com, meta.stackoverflow.com and serverfault.com

**Upcoming Version**

- Browse user profiles
- Syntax highlighting
- Ideas needed...

[image: Select a site menu]
[image: Viewing an answer]

Comment: Post a screenshot of this question on the iPhone, for meta-ness.  (I don't have an iPhone)

Comment: I can't because it doesn't work with meta.stackoverflow.com at present. Sorry.

Comment: I bet if someone were feeling skippy and the app works by sending requests directly to stackoverflow.com, someone could route all requests to/from http://www.stackoverflow.com to http://meta.stackoverflow.com on their wifi network and proceed accordingly

Comment: @snicker yeah that would probably work. Looking at the html code it's nearly exactly the same. I'll add meta in the next version anyway.

Comment: You just made my day

Comment: i downloaded it, but it says Stack...rflow instead. did i do it wrong?

Comment: @qntmfred, nah that's normal, it's because `StackOverflow` is too long to fit in the icon width, so the iPhone strips out the middle of the name.

Comment: yeah i know. just mocking _users_. still looks a little silly. not sure if there's a more appropriate name that avoids that problem

Comment: iS[OFU(E)] might work for the name.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but @BenReeves, your profile's web site link seems broken because it has "www". There are two ways you could fix this. The non-www URL works fine: http://benreeves.co.uk/

Comment: @Cawas Thanks, I'll take a look. It's a personal site really anyway, nobody goes on it.

Answer (score 6):

I like it so far. Any plans to support the rest of the trilogy or other StackExchange sites? Or posting content?

Comment: Pretty please! I'm a ServerFaulter, so the SO isn't particularly useful for me (but I'll download it anyway)

Comment: I've just tested the app with meta.stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com and mathoverflow.net and everyone worked perfectly. Got to love it when everything comes together nicely. I've never used howtogeek.com or doctype.com and their designs are too different to work out the box, so I won't be integrating them.

Comment: @Ben howtogeek and doctype are not part of the trilogy so there's no need to bring them into the mix.

Answer (score 3):

Please do a blackberry app.  I'll buy.

Comment: Just to note, I've now switched over the the Iphone but I'll leave this answer up for Blackberry users.

Answer (score 3):

nice to see an app out there finally. couple things i noticed

- the refresh feed icon looks like it's stuck/frozen when not animating
- get rid of the refresh feed bar. move it to the top right corner maybe?
- when you scroll to the top and bottom, it doesn't do the elastic animation
- make tags buttons to browse that tag's questions

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed the elastic animation. Didn't really bother me though.

Comment: I kind of like the refresh bar at the top, the idea is from the facebook app which is one of the most popular apps in the store. All the other points you mentioned should be fixed. Ben

Answer (score 2):

Like the idea - code samples don't render so well (too wide) in mobile Safari - but there's a long way to go.

I'm reluctant to directly link to it, but I see there is a *paid* app in the app store that purports to be a viewer for SO, but doesn't make clear whether it is directly affiliated or not.  Includes a screen shot with Jeff's name and well-known Coding Horror icon - which seems a bit off if it isn't "official".

Comment: no that isn't official.

Comment: maybe it's the official Code Complete app

Answer (score 2):

Love it, look forward to the next release!

One thing though - timezones need some work. Everything is "11 hours ago" for me (GMT+11)

Answer (score 1):

Can someone port this to Windows? It looks better than the current site -- and it seems ot have less advertisements. Maybe you could add Yahoo Questions, and Experts Exchange too that way it isn't so one sided. That will probably also widen the adoption, Yahoo Answers is still the 600lb gorilla.

Comment: If you could just keep your reputation above 200, you would see far fewer advertisements.